# How to perfectly align an svg grid atop an html grid

Tags: css, svg

I want to place grid lines and vertices atop a CSS Grid layout. I'm trying to figure out if this is possible by only using `width`, `height`, and `viewBox`.

**I am specifically trying to lay the `svg` atop the `div`. So a suggestion to draw everything in an svg is not what I'm trying to do.**

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/4nx7aqwg/1/

I'd like to have everything inside of the svg using unit lengths. So if I want to draw a line from `0,0` to `2,2`, it could be:

```
<path d="M 0 0 L 2 2"></path>
```

---

I've tried working out some math to set the viewBox such that a single unit length works out to the width of the html grid cell (plus the `grid-gap`?)

With 9 columns, that's 8 grid lines between the cells. Each grid line is 2px (`grid-gap:2px`). So each cell would be `(600-(8*2))/9 = 64.888888889px`

**Attempt 1:**
If I had an svg line from `0,0` to `1,0`, I would want it to start from the left side of the `2px` border and extend to the end of the `2px` grid gap. Does this mean I need `1 svg unit = 64.888888889px + 2px + 2px = 68.888888889px`? In which case I'd have `viewBox="0 0 8.767741935 8.767741935"`

**Attempt 2:**
If I have an svg path with width 4, then it's width extends out from the center. So this might actually mean I need `1 svg unit = 64.888888889px + 1px + 1px = 66.888888889px`? In which case I'd have `viewBox="0 0 9.029900332 9.029900332"`

These don't work correctly.

---

Related questions:

- I set `vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;` on the `path` elements. Does this mean `stroke-width="2"` will give a `2px` wide stroke? Or would I need to figure out the `stroke-width` based on my current `viewBox`?
- Is this a futile effort? Will all the decimals ensure I can never align this correctly?
- Should I give up on simple unit measurements inside the svg (`<path d="M 0 0 L 2 2"></path>`) and instead try to figure what the coordinates should be based on my cell widths (e.g. `<path d="M 0 0 L 129.77776 129.77776"></path>`)

---

More context -- I have pre-existing html/css grid via `display:grid;` & `grid-gap:2px`. This div is `600x600`. Each "cell" is `(600-(8*2))/9=64.8888`.

[image: no padding just gap]

But it does not have an outer edge, so I apply a `padding:2px`. The "whole" grid is now `604x604`:

[image: padding and gap]

Currently, I want to absolutely position an svg atop the grid and draw over it (in a draw mode that has vertices). Note how the top/left vertices are flush against the edge and above the padding (incorrectly, but still -- they are flush because the view clips them). I'd like the right/bottom vertices to be the same. All the circles should be centered exactly where two grid lines intersect.

This is the result if the svg has `viewBox="0 0 9 9" width="600" height="600"`

[image: svg on top]

So I want all the edges to sit flush, so I need the svg to be `604x604`. Does a value `x` exist such that `viewBox="0 0 x x"` will give me what I'm looking for?

This next example has `viewBox="0 0 9 9"` still. Notice how the first blue line is slightly to the left of the grid line and the last blue line is slightly to the right. The lines shift due to the incorrect viewBox:

[image]

Result with `viewBox="0 0 9 9" width="600" height="600"`:

[image: svg on top]

Result with `viewBox="0 0 9 9" width="604" height="604"`:

[image]

So I'm trying to align a grid, perfectly, atop the div. If I can perfectly align a grid, then I can align everything else correctly and have the drawn lines lay on top of the grid lines.

Answer (score 1):

You don't fully explain what you want to achieve.  If you are looking for pixel-perfect alignment, then you may be disappointed.  I would expect there to be differences in the pixel rounding of the HTML layout engine and the CSS rendering engine.

> With 9 columns, that's 8 grid lines between the cells. Each grid line is 2px (grid-gap:2px). So each cell would be (600-(8*2))/9 = 64.888888889px

That looks correct.  However remember that you have a 2px padding on the HTML grid.  That doesn't need to be considered in the above calculation, as the HTML engine does not include it in the 600px.  But it **is** affecting the size of your `#container` and thus your SVG also.  Your SVG will be `604px` wide.  With your `"0 0 9 9"` viewBox, one SVG unit (`1`/`1px`) will be equivalent to `67.1111` CSS pixels.

So, relative to the container and the SVG, cell 3 in your CSS grid will start at:

```
2px + 3 * 64.8888px + (3 * 2px)
= 202.6666
```

Whereas in the SVG it will start at

```
3 * 67.1111
= 201.3333
```

You might consider moving the `2px` padding from the #grid to the #container, so that the  #grid and #svg-grid start out at the same size.

> I set vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke; on the path elements. Does this mean stroke-width="2" will give a 2px wide stroke? Or would I need to figure out the stroke-width based on my current viewBox?

Yes. The stroke will always be `2px` no matter what the scale of the SVG is.  Be aware though that `vector-effect` is not supported by all browsers.

> Is this a futile effort? Will all the decimals ensure I can never align this correctly?

Honestly, yes.

> Should I give up on simple unit measurements inside the svg () and instead try to figure what the coordinates should be based on my cell widths (e.g. )

If you need as much pixel accuracy as possible, then this is probably the best approach.  And the calculations will be easier if you resolve the padding issue mentioned above.

Comment: Good answer. Simple and accurate explanation of the subtleties SVG